# How to find pytorch source file for editing

Tags: python, linux, pytorch

how can I find the location of a pytorch file?
ex: `torch.utils.tensorboard`

I want to edit the source code in tensorboard manually. Where are these files located usually?
[image: see for example this list of folders]

Where the packages are downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

It is easily done if you use IPython. After you import a module, you can use the help character `?` after the module name to get this information. For example, on my Ubuntu machine:

```
In [2]: from torch.utils import tensorboard
In [3]: tensorboard?
Type:        module
String form: <module 'torch.utils.tensorboard' from '/home/itamar/miniconda3/envs/drvpy37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/__init__.py'>
File:        ~/miniconda3/envs/drvpy37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/__init__.py
Docstring:   <no docstring>
```

You see that you get the full path of the file where the module is defined.
Then you can edit it manually. Note that in this case, the `tensorboard` module is imported inside an `__init__.py` file, so you will have to open this file in order to track the source file you want to edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot!

When I use 'tensorboard?' letter on python code, it returned SyntaxError with a message "invalid syntax". I got source of the file successfully with "tensorboard" command.

Comment: As I wrote, this works in an interactive `IPython` session, not in a python code that you run.